# npm installing old versions of (typescript compiler) package

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, npm-install, tsc

On a windows environment, I have:
node v4.6.0
npm  v3.10.8

my local typescript version is:

`npm run tsc -v`

3.10.8

However, I sometimes want to use my global tsc (because for some reason, gulp uses the global tsc) but when I do:

`npm install tsc -g
tsc -v`

I get a version 1.5.3 for my typescript compiler

when I try to force install it to the exact version I need:

`npm install tsc@3.10.8 -g`

I get:
`
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\DT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "tsc@3.10.8" "-g"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: tsc@3.10.8
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 1.20150623.0, 1.20150622.0, 1.20150619.0, 1.0.0
`

Btw with my default installation of node, my npm version is 2 something but I can update it to 3.10.8, that works. For typescript however, no way.

Any ideas?

PS:my platform is windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and this worked for me:

1. Go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs" and delete the TypeScript folder.
2. Uninstall previous version (npm uninstall -g typescript)
3. Reinstall typescript.

Answer (score 0):

It's not tsc but typescript that you need to install

`npm uninstall -g tsc
npm install -g typescript`