# Unable to uninstall typescript globally through npm

Tags: node.js, npm-install, tsc

I've installed typescript 2.4.1 on my system globally (tsc -v gives me version 2.4.1). I want to uninstall it as I want to go to version 2.3.4 for some of my e2e tests to work. But right now I'm unable to uninstall it. I tried to uninstall through npm

```
npm uninstall -g tsc
```

but after running the command when I run

```
tsc -v
```

it again shows me

```
version  2.4.1.
```

I've search this problem and found some solutions

[uninstalling typescript without node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393590/uninstalling-typescript-without-node) 
and 
[npm installing old versions of (typescript compiler) package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941592/npm-installing-old-versions-of-typescript-compiler-package) 
but I've tried all i.e. try to find if in installed programs but could not find it. 
Then going into

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript
```

to delete the folder manually but there was version 2.3, not 2.4.1 which its showing in command prompt.

Any help how can I get rid of typescript 2.4.1. ?

Comment: `npm uninstall -g typescript`

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44079091/928435

Answer (score 15):

Please type:

```
npm uninstall -g typescript
```

instead of

```
npm uninstall -g tsc
```

That should solve your problem! :)

Answer (score 8):

## FOR WINDOWS

You might have an old TypeScript installation on your computer because of a Microsoft SDK:

```
cmd>tsc --version
Version 1.0.3.0
```

If you check the `PATH` environment variable, you may find an entry like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\
```

In my case, the uninstallation of "TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015" did not remove `tsc.exe` etc. from this path, probably because it was installed as part of the Windows 10 SDK or something else.

You can remove the entry from the `PATH` environment variable or at least move it below the entry for Node.js (probably `C:\Program Files\nodejs`) or nvm (like `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\nvm`) in case you use Node Version Manager. This will prevent that calls to `tsc` run the ancient TypeScript compiler:

```
cmd>tsc --version
Version 3.1.3
```

Don't forget to restart your command line after changes to environment variables for them to take effect!

If you are unsure what binary the `tsc` command will actually run then use the `where` command to find out:

```
cmd>where tsc
C:\Program Files\nodejs\tsc
C:\Program Files\nodejs\tsc.cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.js
```

The priority is top to bottom. The first entry in my case is a (Linux) shell script and usually not executable on Windows. The second entry is a Windows Batch script and this is the one that will be executed. It basically invokes Node.js (simplified):

```
node.exe node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
```

**OR**

You can now uninstall "TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015" from the Control Panel in Programs and Features. It was automatically installed with Visual Studio 2015 in my case.

---

## FOR Ubuntu Linux

Uninstall node-typescript
To uninstall only node-typescript from Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove node-typescript
```

Uninstall node-typescript and dependent packages
To uninstall the node-typescript package and any other dependent packages that are no longer needed by Ubuntu Xenial.

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove node-typescript
```

Expunge node-typescript
If you also want to clear the node-typescript settings and / or data from Ubuntu Xenial then use this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge node-typescript
```

To clear the node-typescript settings and / or data files and their Ubuntu Xenial dependent packages, run:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove node-typescript
```

**More information about apt-get remove**

Advanced Package Tool, or APT, is a free software user interface that works with core libraries to handle the installation and removal of software on Debian, Ubuntu and other Linux distributions. APT simplifies the process of managing software on Unix-like computer systems by automating the retrieval, configuration and installation of software packages, either from precompiled files or by compiling source code.

apt-get is the command-line tool for handling packages, and may be considered the back end user to other tools using the APT library.

apt-get remove is identical to install except that packages are removed instead of installed. Note that removing a package leaves its configuration files on the system. If a plus sign is appended to the package name (with no intervening space), the identified package will be installed instead of removed.

Comment: He is removing TypeScript from windows platform, not ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

FOR LINUX:

if npm uninstall doens't work - try this command with sudo. This is the way out for me

```
sudo npm uninstall -g typescript

sudo npm uninstall -g tsc
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Fedora 36 I had to do:

```bash
sudo dnf remove nodejs-typescript
```

Command output:

```
Dependencies resolved.ejs-typescript
=============================================================================
 Package              Architecture   Version           Repository  Size
=============================================================================
Removing:
 nodejs-typescript    noarch         4.1.3-4.fc36      @fedora     53 M

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================
Remove  1 Package
```

---

Then to get the latest version I did:

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are missing

```
sudo
```

Do something like this below:

```
npm uninstall -g typescript
```